# "correndo" é um verbo no gerúndio?

Tags: verbos, coloquialismos, classe-gramatical

Colloquially, when verb "correr" is used in the present participle ("correndo") it can mean "quickly", "fast", or "without any delay"

e.g.

- "Sua fofoqueira! Você **foi correndo** contar pra ele."
- "Tive que **telefonar correndo** para cancelar tudo."
- "Vou ter que **passar correndo** na casa do Pedro para deixar os livros."

**What grammatical category is "correndo in these examples"? A verb?**

**EM PORTUGUÊS**

O verbo correr quando usado no gerúndio pode ter o significado de "rapidamente", "sem perda de tempo" ou "depressa". ex: "Sua fofoqueira! Você foi correndo contar pra ele", "Tive que telefonar correndo para cancelar tudo", "Vou passar correndo na casa do Pedro para deixar os livros".  **Nos exemplos acima, qual a categoria gramatical de "correndo"?**

Comment: Parece um caso típico de gerúndio com função adverbial, mas posso estar enganado.

Comment: In those expressions, "correndo" has the exact same usage as "quickly". So it is an adverb.

Comment: A quick note: be warned that English and Portuguese use the terms *gerund* and *present participle* differently. What Portuguese call *gerúndio* is the adverbial use, whereas what English confusingly calls a *gerund* is a substantive use, and it calls *present participle* the adverbial and adjectival uses. An English gerund can be a subject, but in Portuguese you need an infinitive for that. See [this infopédia article in Portuguese on the gerúndio](http://www.infopedia.pt/$gerundio) or [the Wikipedia article on Formas nominais do verbo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formas_nominais_do_verbo).

Comment: @tchrist Am I wrong in using "present participle" at the top?

Comment: @Centaurus No, you are not wrong. English is just strange. In "He came in running" or "He is running faster today than ever", English calls *running* a present participle, but in "Running quickly is the way to win", English traditionally calls the same word a gerund.

Comment: @tchrist I was taught that at school.  A verb in the present participle translates as "gerúndio" in Portuguese. And a verb in the gerund becomes infinitive in Portuguese.  He came running = Ele veio correndo.   Working ten hours a day is going to kill you = Trabalhar dez horas por dia....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Mode Adverb

In all three phrases, you're using *correndo* as a verb modifier, which is the function of an adverb:

> ### Adverb
>
> Invariable word that functions as a modifier of a verb ("dormir pouco"), an adjective ("muito bom"), another adverb ("deveras astuciosamente"), a phrase ("felizmente ele chegou"), expressing circumstances of time, manner, place, quality, cause, intensity, opposition, affirmation, denial, doubt, approval etc.

In all the three examples, *correndo* is a synonym for the word *depressa* (***quickly***, in english).

Comment: What do you mean by "substantive"?   A noun or a word functioning as a noun?

Comment: Sorry, wrong word. It is "synonym", not "substantive".

Comment: You are right that the entire gerund phrase/clause normally acts adverbially. But unlike an adverb yet like most other verb forms, the gerund itself can accept an enclitic object complement (direct or indirect) in Portuguese. For example,  “Vimos o homen dando-lhe o livra” or perhaps “Dizendo-nos exatamente o que queria, João pediu a nossa ajuda.” However, when a gerund with a clitic complement is used with a tensed verb, that object may move earlier in the verb phrase to come before that tensed verb, which is called [clitic climbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clitic_climbing).